# Prove if $n \in \mathbb{Z} - \mathbb{N}$, then max$(nA)=n$ min$(A)$, for $nA = \left\{na \left| \right. a \in A \right\}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having trouble with the following:

> Let $A$ be a nonempty bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Define $nA = \left\{na \left| \right. a \in A \right\}$. Prove the following:
>   If $n \in \mathbb{Z} - \mathbb{N}$, then max$(nA)=n$ min$(A)$.

I started out by writing:

Suppose $n \in \mathbb{Z} - \mathbb{N}$, i.e. $n \in \left\{...,-2,-1,0 \right\}$. If $n=0$, the result is trivial.

If $n<0$, and we let $m=$min$(A)$, then $m=A^l \cap A$, where $A^l$ denotes the set of all lower bounds of $A$. Now $nm=n \cdot A^l \cap A$.

I'm not sure where to go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier than that since $ \forall a : a \geq \min(A)$. Then multiplying by $n$ changes the inequality and finally, you know that the maximum is in $A$ :)